# What flattening technique is used when a pant / trouser length is altered?

Tags: sewing

When purchasing a new pant, it needs to be altered to the length of my leg. When I get the alteration at a branded store, the edge is nice and flat, as shown in the image below.
[image]

However, when I give it to a local tailor for alteration, the edge ends up puffy as shown in the images below.
[image]
[image]

The tailor said it'd become flat after ironing, but it didn't.
My question is, about what sewing technique is used to make the edge flat like in the first image? If I know what to tell the tailor, at least they'd do it properly next time...or at least I'll be able to fix those two black pants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tailor should have pressed it properly.

They really need to press down on the iron. When I worked in the tailor shop & costume shop, I gained new shoulder muscles.

The heat has to be high, steam or spraying water on the fabric helps and pressing on a very sturdy table (not a consumer ironing board).
The tailor shop also had a wooden Padded Sleeve Ironing Board on top of a table. The hem can be placed like a sleeve over it for better focus.

workaround: take to the dry cleaner to press it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tailor didn't heat the iron to a high enough temperature to alter how the fibers naturally lie. That fabric looks like synthetic (not organic) fiber to me. There's a sweet spot for temp on synthetic fabrics. Too high can melt/burn through the fabric, but too low doesn't flatten anything. Your home iron probably has a couple of settings for synthetics (eg nylon); try them from low to high until it works

Answer (score 0):

removing any excess fabric may also help with keeping the pressed seam thin.

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  Could you elaborate a little on what would constitute excess fabric?  Thanks.